# Transmute_at every column based on another column in r

Tags: r

I have a DF4 table with 1500 columns ending with .SH all but the last column that's called change that looks like this:

```
Date    123.SH  111.SH 222.SH 444.SH ...... change 
09/01   -0.2    -0.1   -0.5   -0.1           -0.1
09/02   -3.2    -0.4   -5.3   -0.4           -0.3
etc      ...     ...    ...    ...            ...
```

The numbers here basically represents the maximum decrease of change (%) each company experienced every month, for example 123.SH in 09/01 had a maximum -0.2 or -20% drop in their price. The change is the average change of all 1500 companies.

My goal is set flags for every one of the columns to see if each decrease is greater than 20% of the change, 1 for yes, 0 for no. I want it to look like this ideally:

```
    Date    123.SH  111.SH 222.SH 444.SH ...... change 
    09/01    0       0       1      0           -0.1
    09/02    1       0       1      0           -0.3
    etc      ...     ...    ...    ...            ...
```

So this is the code that I tried:

```
flag= df4 %>% group_by(Date) %>% transmute_at(.vars=vars(ends_with("SH")),
                                               .funs=funs(case_when((.)-"change"<=-0.2~1,
                                                                     (.)-"change">-0.2~0)))
```

However, I get an error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `123.SH`.
> x non-numeric argument to binary operator
> i Input `123.SH` is `case_when(...)`.

Did it also transmute my first name column? Could "ifelse" be applicable to this situation, I'm more familiar with case_when. Is there any solution to fix this problem? Any insight would be helpful! I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subtract the `change` column values with all the columns that we want and assign 1 if the value is less than -0.2.

```
cols <- grep('\\.SH', names(df))
df[cols] <- +((df[cols] - df$change) < -0.2)
df
#   Date 123.SH 111.SH 222.SH 444.SH change
#1 09/01      0      0      1      0   -0.1
#2 09/02      1      0      1      0   -0.3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("09/01", "09/02"), `123.SH` = c(-0.2, 
-3.2), `111.SH` = c(-0.1, -0.4), `222.SH` = c(-0.5, -5.3), `444.SH` = c(-0.1, 
-0.4), change = c(-0.1, -0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all your help!!! However I have it to be less than -0.2 compared to the 'change' column, for example, 111.Sh compared to 'change'  the difference is only -0.1 so I would want it to be 0.

Comment: Great let me try!